# Why isn't my cache manifest kicking in?

Tags: html, cache-manifest

This is driving me crazy to no end. My cache-manifest isn't loading. And I have no idea why not.

The header is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <html manifest="default.appcache">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/splash/splash-icon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/splash-screen.png"
        media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/splash-screen@2x.png"
        media="(max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
        />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <title>Ez Names</title>
```

Comment: Hi @das_boot. Links tend to rot. So to ensure this question also is valuable to visitors after you fix the problem on your site, can you ensure that the relevant fragment of your cache-manifest is in your question?

Comment: Included cache manifest in the sample.

Comment: What web server is the page hosted on (apache/iis/nginx/etc)?

Comment: Hostgator. And I think it is Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this ridiculous problem. The cache.manifest has to be defined OUTSIDE of the  field. Such a silly error. But if anyone has troubles, make sure it's in the right place.